# php foreach loop and incorrect placement of html tags

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have an issue regarding placing correct div holders between a php loop.
I am creating a menu with categories and subcateories as shown [in this image](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=sux0z8&s=8#.U5rHJv5xOPI).

The categories can have subcategories, but not always. I have done php code that does this. 
But I have some issue with my php loop and placement of tags inside the foreach loop.

This is the html code of how it should be displayed:

```
<!--Category Menu -->
<div class='categoriesmenuFather ' id='nav-cat' style='display:block' >
<div class='categories_list categoriesmenu '>
 <ul class='level1'>

<li class='submenu border_t'>
<div class=cat_bg> 
<a title='Electronics' href='#'><span>Electronics</SPAN></a>
</div>

<!--BOF Sub-category-->
<ul class='level2'>
<li><a href="#">LED</a></li>
<li><a href="#">DVD Players</a></li>
</ul>
</li> 
<!--EOF Sub-category-->

<li class='submenu border_t'>
<div class=cat_bg> 
<a title='Electronics' href='#'><span>Computers & Networking</SPAN></a>
</div>

<!--BOF Sub-category-->
<ul class='level2'>
<li><a href="#">Tablet</a></li>
</ul>
</li> 
<!--EOF Sub-category-->

<li class='submenu border_t'>
<div class=cat_bg> 
<a title='Electronics' href='#'><span>Cell Phones</SPAN></a>
</div>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

With my present loop code the html appears as:

```
<!--BOF Left Menu -->
<div class='categoriesmenuFather ' id='nav-cat' style='display:block' >
<div class='categories_list categoriesmenu '>
<ul class='level1'>
<li class='submenu border_t'>

<div class=cat_bg> 
<a title='Electronics' href='products.php?catid=1'><span>Electronics</SPAN></a>
</div>


<!--BOF Sub-category-->
<ul class='level2'>
<li><a href="products.php?catid=1&subcatid=1">LED</a></li>
<li><a href="products.php?catid=1&subcatid=2">DVD Players</a></li>
</ul></li>  
<!--EOF Sub-category-->

<li class='submenu border_t'>   
<div class=cat_bg> 
<a title='Computers' href='products.php?catid=2'><span>Computers & Networking</SPAN></a>
</div>

<!--BOF Sub-category-->
<ul class='level2'>
<li><a href="products.php?catid=2&subcatid=3">Tablet</a></li>
</ul></li>  
<!--EOF Sub-category-->

<li class='submenu border_t'>   
<div class=catall_bg>
<a title='Cell Phones' href='products.php?catid=3'><span>Cell Phones</SPAN></a>
</div>

</ul></li>  
<!--EOF Sub-category-->


<li class='submenu border_t'>
<div class=catall_bg>
<a title='Video Games' href='products.php?catid=4'><span>Video Games</SPAN></a>
</div>
</ul></li>  


 </ul>
</div>
 </div>
```

In a product with no subcategory like cell phone and Video Games the /ul and /li
tags are getting included with the result that the last item appears as displayed [in this image (design changed)](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=fx5wr4&s=8#.U5rEmf5xOPI).

My php code is as follows:

```
<?php
    include_once 'connstring.inc.php';
    //Get records from database
    $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT *, C.category_id
    FROM category C LEFT OUTER JOIN subcategory S
    ON C.category_id = S.category_id AND S.status = 'Enabled' 
    WHERE C.status = 'Enabled'
    ");
    $q->execute();   
    $result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
    if ($result !== false) {
    ?>
    <div class='categoriesmenuFather ' id='nav-cat' style='display:block' >
    <div class='categories_list categoriesmenu '>
     <ul class='level1'>
    <?php
    foreach($result as $key => $rows) {
    if (!empty($rows)) {
    $i = 1;
    foreach($rows as $row) {
    if ($i == 1) {
    ?>
    <li class='submenu border_t'>

    <?php
    //to not display arrow, check for subcategory items is none
    if (is_null($row['subcategory_name']) || (string)$row['subcategory_name'] == ''){
    ?>  
    <div class=catall_bg>
    <a title='<?php echo $row['category_name']; ?>' href='products.php?catid=<?php echo $row['category_id']; ?>'><span><?php echo $row['category_name']; ?></SPAN></a>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <div class=cat_bg> <!--for sub-cat-arrow-->
    <a title='<?php echo $row['category_name']; ?>' href='products.php?catid=<?php echo $row['category_id']; ?>'><span><?php echo $row['category_name']; ?></SPAN></a>
    </div><!--sub-cat-arrow close-->
    <?php
    }
    ?>


    <?php
    //to not display subcategory items if none
    if (is_null($row['subcategory_name']) || (string)$row['subcategory_name'] == ''){
    break;
    }
    ?>  
    <!--BOF Sub-category-->
    <ul class='level2'>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <li><a href="products.php?catid=<?php echo $row['category_id'].'&subcatid='.$row['subcategory_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['subcategory_name']; ?></a></li>
    <?php
    $i++;
     }
    echo'</ul></li>';
    ?>  
    <!--EOF Sub-category-->
    <?php
    }
    }  


    } else {
    throw new PDOException('No records');
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I know that this is an issue with placing tags inside loop.. But I am unable to locate it. Requesting help.

Comment: There's too much code up there to dissect...can you try to simplify this or narrow it down to highlight likely spots where you are running into trouble?

Comment: @Dan The  </ul></li> tags are getting included with the result (category with no subcategories). It is an issue of placing correct tag inside the loop..but unable to detect.What the html should be like and what it in the html code provided above is may provide insight.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this portion:

```
<?php
//to not display subcategory items if none
if (is_null($row['subcategory_name']) || (string)$row['subcategory_name'] == ''){
break;
}
?>  
<!--BOF Sub-category-->
<ul class='level2'>
<?php
}
?>
<li><a href="products.php?catid=<?php echo $row['category_id'].'&subcatid='.$row['subcategory_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['subcategory_name']; ?></a></li>
<?php
$i++;
 }
echo'</ul></li>';
?>  
<!--EOF Sub-category-->
<?php
}
}
```

Here you can find your problem. You are closing a ul tag that wasn't opened because the break;

I think you need to close ul tag if was opened, the "break" solution looks to me a little nasty... better take control that if ul was opened, close ul, if not only need to close li.

Comment: If i removed the break code categories not having subcategories are displayed as a blank placeholder. Image at: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ibdggm&s=8#.U5rljP5xOPI

Comment: The </ul></li> tags are getting included with the result (category with no subcategories). That is where the issue is ...How to change it in loop code ??   The html is <div class=catall_bg>
<a title='Video Games' href='products.php?catid=4'><span>Video Games</SPAN></a>
</div>

</ul>
</li>

Comment: I recommend you to use a recursive function that mount it. Function run and mount the code for each category, and if had children function open ul, call to himself, and close ul.

In this thread in the most voted response you can find that you must use
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333788/php-recursive-function-to-retrieve-all-children-of-a-category

Answer (score 0):

i Think you have to place `<ul class='level2'>` outside the `if ($i == 1) {`

currently it is inside the `if` condition

Comment: If so..where should i place it ?? I tried a lot..Could you please provide a code snippet..

Comment: just after where if condition close. currently it is placed before the if condition closing tag..