# Specif array with root and child categories

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, recursion

Using PHP and MySQL.

I have a table (category) with three fields only, **id**, **name**, **parent**.

Where **parent** is 0 on root category and a integer if it is derived from another.

But we can have several levels inside this, for example:

```
id, name, parent
01, Name 01, 00
02, Name 02, 00
03, Name 03, 00
04, Name 04, 02
05, Name 05, 01
06, Name 06, 01
07, Name 07, 05
08, Name 07, 05
09, Name 09, 04
10, Name 10, 07
11, Name 11, 10
```

How could we return an array containing the root and all of its subnodes? For example, for id=1, the array should be:

```
array (
    1 => array(
        id => 1,
        name => 'Name 1'
    ),
    5 => array(
        id => 5,
        name => 'Name 5'
    ),
    6 => array(
        id => 6,
        name => 'Name 6'
    ),
    7 => array(
        id => 7,
        name => 'Name 7'
    ),
    8 => array(
        id => 8,
        name => 'Name 8'
    ),
    10 => array(
        id => 10,
        name => 'Name 10'
    ),
    11 => array(
        id => 11,
        name => 'Name 11'
    )
);
```

I had take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398402/recursive-function-to-get-all-the-child-categories) and tried some variations but I haddnt success yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL query should get the data you want:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT c.id as id, c.name as name FROM category c, category s WHERE s.parent = $id OR c.id = $id;
```

Then you could use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) to get part of the array you need. If you needed the array indices to match up w/ the SQL indices, then you could just iterate over the result of `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and put into a new array:

```
    $target = array();
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
         $target[$row["id"]] = $row;
    }
```

Comment: Incridible solution. Thanks a lot Michael. Almost I will use a bad solution. Thanks a lot. I just needed to do a little change on your query. Add DISTINCT.