# How can I repeat loop for all categories

Tags: php

I have a loop in PHP that did not really end up like I wanted to since i am not experienced with PHP and could not figure out. I want to repeat a loop to show every post for each category which have tables called "tblcategories" and "tblposts". I want to do 2 categories per row with 2posts each but did not even manage to do more than a single category. Here is the UPDATED code:

```
 <?php   
       $no_of_records_per_page = 2;
       $selectcat = "SELECT * FROM tblcategory"; //get all categories
       $stmt = $con->prepare($selectcat); 
       $stmt->execute();
       $result = $stmt->get_result();
       $counter = 0;
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { //loop all category. here row is single category
           $query="select tblposts.id as pid,tblposts.PostTitle as posttitle,tblposts.PostImage,tblcategory.CategoryName as category,tblcategory.id as cid,tblsubcategory.Subcategory as subcategory,tblposts.PostDetails as postdetails,tblposts.PostingDate as postingdate,tblposts.PostUrl as url from tblposts left join tblcategory on tblcategory.id=tblposts.CategoryId left join  tblsubcategory on  tblsubcategory.SubCategoryId=tblposts.SubCategoryId where tblposts.Is_Active=1 and tblposts.CategoryId=? order by tblposts.id desc  LIMIT ?";
           $stmt = $con->prepare($query); 
           $stmt->bind_param("ii", $row['id'], $no_of_records_per_page);
           $stmt->execute();
           $resultt = $stmt->get_result();
           
           if ($counter % 2 == 0) echo "<div class='row'>"; //here we open row for each even category, so 0, 2, 4,...
           else $counter++;
       
           
           echo "<div class='col-md-5'>";
       
           while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultt)) {
               echo "<div class='col-md-12'>"; ?>

<h2 style="text-align:center;" ><a href="category.php?catid=<?php echo htmlentities($row1['cid'])?>"><?php echo htmlentities($row1['category']);?></a></h2>
                <hr> 
                    
                <div class="post-preview"><a href="news-details.php?nid=<?php echo htmlentities($row1['pid'])?>">
                        <img class="post-title" src="admin/postimages/<?php echo htmlentities($row1['PostImage']);?>" alt="<?php echo htmlentities($row1['posttitle']);?>" style="width:250px; height:auto; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
                        <h2 style="font-size:20pt;" class="post-title"><?php echo htmlentities($row1['posttitle']);?></h2>
                        
                    </a>
                    <p class="post-meta"><b>Category : </b> <a href="category.php?catid=<?php echo htmlentities($row1['cid'])?>"><?php echo htmlentities($row1['category']);?></a> <br><?php echo htmlentities($row1['postingdate']);?></a></p>
                </div>
                <hr>

       <?php
               // show here post from $row1
       
               echo "</div>";
           }
           echo "</div>";
           if ($counter % 2 == 1) echo "</div>"; //here we close row for category so, 1, 3, 5,...
       }
        ?>
```

[image: Something like this, without the sidebar, i will figure the sidebar out later]

Comment: This answer may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398402/recursive-function-to-get-all-the-child-categories

Comment: Can you more explain your question? You want to show each category with 2 posts per row?

Comment: @FarhodNematov so each row in table "tblcategory" is where the categories are. "tblposts" contains posts that goes in to different categories stored in tblcategory. as you can see in the code there are row and columns (row does not work in my code), i want to list one category per column, and two posts right under it per category. after 2 columns of categories are shown, next category should be next row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't totally understand you, but I think you have to select all categories first, then with while loop you have to select its posts.

Your html structure should be like this

[image]

So like this:

```php
$no_of_records_per_page = 2;
$selectcat = "SELECT * FROM tblcategory"; //get all categories
$stmt = $con->prepare($selectcat); 
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$counter = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { //loop all category. here row is single category
    $query="select tblposts.id as pid,tblposts.PostTitle as posttitle,tblposts.PostImage,tblcategory.CategoryName as category,tblcategory.id as cid,tblsubcategory.Subcategory as subcategory,tblposts.PostDetails as postdetails,tblposts.PostingDate as postingdate,tblposts.PostUrl as url from tblposts left join tblcategory on tblcategory.id=tblposts.CategoryId left join  tblsubcategory on  tblsubcategory.SubCategoryId=tblposts.SubCategoryId where tblposts.Is_Active=1 and tblposts.CategoryId=? order by tblposts.id desc  LIMIT ?";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $row['id'], $no_of_records_per_page);
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultt = $stmt->get_result();
    
    if ($counter % 2 == 0) echo "<div class='row'>"; //here we open row for each even category, so 0, 2, 4,...
    else $counter++;

    
    echo "<div class='col-md-5'>"; //open col for row posts category title will be inside col-5

    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultt)) {
        echo "<div class='col-md-12'>";

        // show here post from $row1

        echo "</div>";
    }
    echo "</div>"; // close col-5
    if ($counter % 2 == 1) echo "</div>"; //here we close row for category so after two col-5 row will be close
}
```

Comment: This is nearly what i wanted, everything is fine, only thing is, each 2 category should be in same row, next row should come after 2nd category from previous row

Comment: @tsundok I have updated answer, check it please

Comment: i have checked it and it is great so far, but only problem is, it every time opens 2 rows and for each row it is 2 columns but only for the same category side to side, i will upload an image to the post to show what i need

Comment: I have added the image, but without the sidebar, i can figure it out later so I dont tire you too much

Comment: Saw your comment in the code "row is single category" , each row should be 2 categories, only column will be 1 category

Comment: You can't get by two item from sql. You have show posts inside single category and with html you will correct it. I have updated my answer see it

Comment: row -> [col-md-5 -> col-12, col-12], [col-md-12 -> col-12, col-12]
row -> [col-md-5 -> col-12, col-12], [col-md-12 -> col-12, col-12]
row -> [col-md-5 -> col-12, col-12], [col-md-12 -> col-12, col-12]

Your html structure to be like this

Comment: now it shows 2 posts per category but 1 column per row, I will update post to how it is currently

Comment: the drawing you did on my image is exactly what needed

Comment: Did you check html structure with browser inspect element? Can you add html structure result?

Comment: I have edited the post and added the result after first code

Comment: The row closes after each category instead of each 2 category

Comment: checked last update, row still closes after each category and for 2nd post col becomes col-12

Comment: @tsundok I have find my error. move $counter++ from else body to end of the first while loop. So
while (...){ ... if ($counter % 2 == 0) // here is no else. 
....
//last line of while
`
$counter++;
`
}

Comment: Wonderful everything is perfect now, at first I have realised the else mistake but could not think of the position... Thank you for your help... lastly do you know where I can replace a sidebar for 3rd column if you have time, if not it is totally fine i am satisfied

Comment: I can't understand your question. If you want to show categories on right sidebar, simply collect categories to array and use it all places

Comment: I mean, remember the picture i have in my post ? at the right side there is a sidebar which i connect from sidebar.php

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember. If you need any help, you can make new question